# Flex socket-to-socket

Tags: flash, apache-flex, sockets

Is it possible to communicate between two running copies of one Flex application through Flash sockets? If true, then how?

E.g.: if we have chat application, one of running chat should connect directly to another one. While both of them use `flash.net.Socket` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AS3, it is possible only if you use AIR application as a 'server':
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/articles/creating_socket_server.html

In case you want to communicate bwetween two remote apps, you should consider P2P:
http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/

Answer (score 0):

The Flash Player does not allow you to listen to sockets, so no, you can't do that.

You should use `flash.net.LocalConnection` for local communication.

Comment: and what should i use for remote one? =)